# AndEngine. DetachChild in BaseLiveWallpaperService

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, live-wallpaper

I try to create wallpaper and use for that *AndEngineLiveWallpaper*. So, I sometimes catch *IndexOutOfBoundsException*, when try to detach child sprite from scene. I now, that I must use *runOnUpdateThread*, but it useful only on *BaseGameActivity*.

How can I fix that in *BaseLiveWallpaperService*?

Comment: How do you try to detach the sprite?

Comment: I use different solutions:
scene.getChildByTag(tag).detachSelf();
scene.detachChild(tag);
scene.detachChild(sprite);
But, nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your Engine runOnUpdateThread method:

```
mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new DetachChildRunnable())
```